# Download a large file or show error

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, xmlhttprequest, fileapi

On a website we are working on, we have a download link, that must be served to the user. However, when fetching the url the server can either serve an error message in JSON (the appropriate headers and an appropriate http status code will then be set) or serve the file.

Currently, we are using an iframe to download this file, but this prevents us from viewing the error message. While, this can be done in principle, it cannot be done cross-domain and the reading the error data seems to be different between browsers (as the browser will interpret the json as html and create html tags around it)

I have considered using xmlhttprequest2 to download the file, and serve it to the user, however the downloaded file can be large and thus, it must be streamed to the user.

Therefore, I'm looking for a way to either download a file or read the error message depending on the http status code.

**API Setup**

I'm able to change the API to my wishes, however the API is designed to be a public API and is designed as a REST API. This means, that the API should stay as simple as possible, and workarounds to make specific client-side code work should not have cause any hazzle for other client-side (thus the API and client-side code are decoupled).

The file that is being downloaded is encrypted on the server, and can only be decrypted by information given in the URL. Therefore, chunked transfer is difficult, as extracting a chunk would require the server to decrypt the whole file.

Comment: Do you have control over the server response? Can you change the response be either an error code and error message or a success code and file url? If so, you could just make an ajax call and on success redirect to the url. If this won't work, please explain what about your setup would prevent this.

Comment: What is expected `MIME` type of file?

Comment: @TinMonkey, yes I do. But in general, any error would be an exception and I'd rather make one single request, but I just started to implement using the HEAD approach described below. It also concerns a REST API, so such a redirect would not really fit into the design, but an approach with HEAD of course would :).

Comment: @guest271314 application/octet-stream

Comment: Would you be able to redirect on error?
You could then redirect the error to a url containing the error in the hash. The site could then do a smiple 
window.parent.functionToDisplayError(error)

Comment: Any reasons why you do not want to keep the iframe- solution? Just return a custom error page and include the JSON error in a variable (script), use document.domain to eliminate cross origin errors. So your iframe-errorPage can notify your current page onLoad/onError calling a handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the appropriate headers and an appropriate http status code will then be set

If that statement is correct, you could use the same concept as [preflighted requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) for Cross-site requests. Preflighted requests first send an HTTP request with the `OPTIONS` method to the resource on the other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe to send or not.

In your case, instead of having an `OPTIONS` request automatically send, you could send manually an `HEAD` request. The `HEAD` method is identical to `GET` except that the server do not return a message-body in the response. The informations contained in the HTTP headers in response to a `HEAD` request should be identical to the information sent in response to a `GET` request. Since you're only fetching the headers and not the body, you would have no problem with large or even any file, nothing is downloaded except the headers.

Then, you can read these headers or even the status code, and depending on the result of this manually preflighted request, decide if you should either stream the file to the user or fetch the error message if you're encountering an error.

A basic implementation without knowledge of your project using status code could be the following:

```
function canDownloadFile(url, callback)
{
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open('HEAD', url);
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      callback(http.status);
    }
  };

  http.send();
}

var canDownloadCallback = function (statusCode) {
  if (statusCode === 200) {
    // The HEAD request returned an OK status code, the GET will do the same,
    // let's download the file...
  } else {
    // The HEAD request returned something else, something is wrong,
    // let's fetch the error message and maybe display it...
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, this is exactly what I'm implementing right now! I was hoping there would be some single request alternative, but if not, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can return to iframe JS code which would send message to parent window via postMessage, in this way you could capture errors in host window. There wouldn't be any problems with cross-domain, and content easily would be streamed to browser as it was before.

Comment: That would require me to fit the server response to the client response which shouldn't necessarily be a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could use single request, return response as a `Blob`, check `Blob.type` to determine where to utilize `FileReader` `.result` to retrieve `JSON` text from `Blob` and display error message, or set `src` of `<img>` element using `URL.createObjectURL`

```
var result = document.querySelector("div");

fetch("/path/to/resource")
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(blob => {
  if (blob.type === "application/json") {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      result.innerHTML = JSON.parse(e.target.result).error
    };
    reader.readAsText(blob);
  } else {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    result.appendChild(img);
  }
});
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/wrzLNm1Sp4k1mfNrYOlQ?p=preview

Comment: Does this work with large files? This would load the whole file in memory, right?

Comment: @user23127 _"Does this work with large files?"_ Have you tried?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't.

Comment: @user23127 Yes, the file can be downloaded using pattern at Answer. Used approach at plnkr which simulated `JSON`being returned randomly and handled at `.then()`. If file is returned you can use same `objectURL` which is set as `<img>` `src` as file to download using `<a>` element with `download` attribute set, which would require only one request to serve if file is response. See version 2 at https://plnkr.co/edit/NLBe8XrgX4YxhLkAJL56?p=info , where when `JSON` is not returned as response `Save File` dialog is displayed; try running plnkr several occasions until file is returned as response.

Comment: But then the file is still downloaded before it is saved so it must be loaded somewhere in the memory.